# My Api data is not displaying on my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im making a project where I fetch an image of a recipe card from https://spoonacular.com and I want it displayed on my react.js app. For some reason I can't get the API data from displaying on the page when I run it. Please help Im really stuck

This is my Home.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Recipe from "../components/Recipes";

const URL = `https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/4632/card?apiKey=${APIKey}`;

function Home() {
  const [food, setFood] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (food) {
      axios
        .get(URL)
        .then(function (response) {
          const recipeList = response.data;
          setFood(recipeList);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.warn(error);
        });
    }
  }, [food]);

  return (
    <>
      <main>
        <Recipe recipeList={food} />
      </main>
    </>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

and this is my Recipe.js

```
import React from "react";

function Recipe({ recipeList }) {
  return (
    <section className="RecipeCard">
      <div
        className="Recipe"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: recipeList }}
      />
    </section>
  );
}

export default Recipe;
```

Comment: 1) Do not include credentials like an API key in your question. 2) Does the response actually contain HTML? It would appear that it actually responds with JSON which will not work with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Comment: the response is json data and Im just confused on how I would display the data on the actual html page and if not use dangerouslySetInnerHTML then what should I use? sorry im new to react and integrating apis

Comment: While the API key has been edited out and is in the process of being erased from the revision history, there's nothing we can do about third party sites. If you haven't already, I urge you to invalidate the API key and get a new one

Answer (score 0):

You need to output the JSON as HTML for it to display.

For example, get a specific [recipe](https://spoonacular.com/food-api/docs#Get-Recipe-Information): https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/716429/information?includeNutrition=false

and in the `Recipe` Component `div`

```
<div className="Recipe">
   {food && <>
    <div>{food.title}</div>
    <img src={food.image} />
   </>}
</div>
```

Comment: I keep getting an error that recipeList is undefined in the recipe.js file... where do I define it then cus I thought I did

Comment: Updated to use the hook variable `food` and only display after being set

Answer (score 0):

```
 <section className="RecipeCard">
  {recipeList.map((recipe, index)=> (
    <div key={index} className="Recipe">
        <h2>{recipe.title}</h2>
   </div>
  ))}
</section>
```

Also, for code readability try to use async-await syntax for API call.

```
useEffect(()=> {
    const getRecipeList = async () => {
       if(food){
         try{
           const { data } = await axios.get(URL);
           setFood(data);
         }catch(error){
           console.log(error);
         }
       }
   }
  getRecipeList(); 
},[food]);
```